# Can you change the Mac OS system highlight color with a terminal command?

Tags: macos

I need to be able to retrieve and/or set the system highlight color from a terminal command.  Does anyone know how to access it?

Thanks.

Comment: `defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist | grep Selec` list a bunch o colors but the active one is not clear.

Comment: The colours in com.apple.Terminal.plist are those for Terminal themes.  @RandySK wants to modify the system highlight colour - as in System Preferences > General > Highlight colour.